Need condition on forloop's one value while updating throught linq
Here is my query.
(from t in Context.Tracker
                             where t.TrackerNumber == Guid.Parse(TrackerNumber)
                             select a).ToList().ForEach((x) =>
                             {
                                 x.Active = true;
                                 x.Formatted = true;
                                 x.TrackerOn = DateTime.UtcNow
                           
                                 dbContext.SaveChanges();
                             });

Tracker is my table.I want update Active and Formatted columns every time. But TrackerOn get updated only if it is null,If TrackerOn it have value , TrackerOn should not get updated.

ForEach <-- This method is not your friend - you should always prefer foreach instead.

LINQ doesn't update, it's a query language. It doesn't talk to databases either. ORMs like NHibernate and EF do, and these work with entities, not tables. Once you load the entities, you modify them and the ORM takes care of persisting the changes

Furthermore, calling dbContext.SaveChanges(); for every loop-iteration is just inefficient  for no benefit...

Not just inefficient - it's a critical bug that completely breaks EF's concurrency model and harms performance. SaveChanges persists all pending changes in all the entities it tracks in a single database transaction. If anything goes wrong, no change is made. By calling SaveChanges on every change, not only is it impossible to recover, but the first SaveChanges can easily perform 42 pending DELETEs as well

The q in linq stands for query and you are writing which is not a query (reading).

LINQ doesn't update or even talk to databases. It's just a query language. ORMs like NHibernate and Entity Framework translate LINQ queries to SQL and map results to objects. It's the ORMs that persist object changes.
The code should look like this. It will run at least N times faster than the original attempt (where N the number of items) and leave no bad data behind if any operation fails:
var trackers=from t in Context.Tracker
             where t.TrackerNumber == Guid.Parse(TrackerNumber)
             select a;
// Modify the in-memory objects
foreach(var tracker in trackers)
{
    x.Active = true;
    x.Formatted = true;
    x.TrackerOn ??= DateTime.UtcNow
}
//Only call once at the very end, to persist all changes
Context.SaveChanges();

The statement x.TrackerOn ??= DateTime.UtcNow is just shorthand for
if (x.TrackerOn ==null) {
    x.TrackerOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
}

SaveChanges should only be called once at the very end. It will persist all pending changes in a single internal database transaction. This is critical. This way, if anything goes wrong, nothing is persisted. If you want to discard the changes, just dispose the DbContext.
EF won't even keep a connection open between the first query and SaveChanges. SaveChanges will open a connection to save the changes and close it before returning.

you are checking x.TrackerOn == null after making sure it won't be null :)

@MichałTurczyn no, I hit Save accidentally while explaining what ??= does. I thought that if the OP doesn't know what LINQ is or what ForEach does, they probably won't know about ??= either
